# Apostol theorem 1.2 possibility of subtraction

Tags: calculus

In Apostol's Calculus Volume I book, there is a theorem, named Possibility of Subtraction, which states:

Given $a$ and $b$, there is exactly one $x$ such that $a+x=b$. This $x$ is denoted by $b−a$. In particular, $0−a$ is written simply $−a$ and is called the negative of $a$.

Its proof is: Given $a$ and $b$, choose $y$ so that $a+y=0$ and let $x=y+b$. Then, $a+x=a+(y+b)=(a+y)+b=0+b=b.$ Therefore there is at least one $x$ such that $a+x=b$. But by (another theorem) there is at most one such $x.$ Hence, there is exactly one.

Now my question is that how do we prove $a - a = 0$ ?
And $-a$ exists? Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for future reference:

You start from axiom 5, which tell you that there is an $x$ such that $y+x=0$. You now use theorem I.2 replacing $y=a$ and $b=0$ to reach $a+x=0$ and there one and only one such $x$. By theorem I.2 you know that $x=0-a$ and you call that $-a$.

Now, to proof that $a-a=0$, you go back to theorem I.2 to reach $-a=0-a$, implying that $-a+a=0$. Now, from axiom 1 we know that $-a+a=a+(-a)=0$, ending the proof.